# javascript not working when the site is hosted

Tags: javascript, web-hosting

I have a search page at http://www.excoflare.com/dev2011/socialnetwork?menu=biz_people_search where I have an advanced search option.

When the user clicks in it it will show up city and country options. But it doesn't work (please go to the link) though it was working fine in localhost. And I think path settings are OK since the CSS is working fine.

Comment: Thanks John,I did not knew that :)

Comment: @emaillenin You r rite  Emaillenin . But sire  this is my first time  and m bt nrvs !!. I will remembr your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the path, you have an extra space after the `?` when you're requesting the file. The server is looking for

```
http://www.excoflare.com/dev2011/socialnetwork/index.php%20?menu=createOptions&ajax=ajax
----------------------------------------------------------^
```

Fixing that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "index.php ?menu=attach_file_2&ajax=ajax";
```

remove extra space here